# VB, how do I check if a certain character is in a string

Tags: vb6

Okay so in visual basic I am trying to read in from a file and the only things I need to read in are all the strings that have a ° at the end of it because it is a temperature. So far I have it so integers will be read in but I dont know how to make it check if there is a ° at the end of it. Here is what I have:

```
Public Function getNextInteger() As Integer

    Dim charInt As String
    Dim chr As String
    Static index As Integer = -1
    index += 1
    chr = numDat(index)

    While Asc(chr) < 48 Or Asc(chr) > 57
        index += 1
        chr = numDat(index)
    End While

    charInt = chr

    While Asc(chr) >= 48 And Asc(chr) <= 57
        index += 1
        chr = numDat(index)
        charInt += chr
    End While

    Return CInt(charInt)

End Function
```

thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because you asked the same thing in a different way just two hours before. possible duplicate of [Visual Basic, importing specific integers from file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32598052/visual-basic-importing-specific-integers-from-file)

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean this?

```
Dim txt As String
txt = "55°"
If Len(txt) > 0 And Right(txt, 1) = "°" Then MsgBox "° found"

If Len(txt) > 0 And Asc(Right(txt, 1)) = 176 Then MsgBox "° found"
```